# Why does vuetify data table group show the same group more than once?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have created a data table with vuetify and tried to group it with a field called **"unit"** like below:

```
<v-data-table
      :loading="loading"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="modifiedChapters"
      item-key="id"
      class="elevation-1"
      disable-sort
      group-by="unit"
      :page.sync="chaptersInput.pageNo"
      :items-per-page="chaptersInput.limit"
      :server-items-length="totalCount"
      @update:options="onUpdatePagination"
    >
```

The output of the code is a bit weird. It is grouping the item more than once with the same name. I have added a photo below for better understanding. Here you see that both the units "Introduction" and "Unit One" are grouped more than once. How can  I solve the issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is cause by `disable-sort`. You can try it by opening [Grouping example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#grouping) in Code Pen - if you add `disable-sort` it will break...

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11905) in Vuetify repo but it is hard to say whether it is a bug or intended behavior as nobody of maintainers commented on it...

Workaround is to not use `disable-sort` and instead set `sortable: false` on each header definition (tested)

Other workaround would be to pre-sort your data yourself by the same column you are passing into `group-by` as the group-by logic apparently (and logically) expects the rows are sorted by the grouping column. But this is of course less practical if you want to allow user to switch grouping by using `show-group-by` prop (also tested)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response. It works perfectly the ways you mentioned. But It breaks again when I use the ":server-items-length" prop. Could you please suggest me something?

Comment: Well if you are using `server-items-length` prop, [Vuetify expects](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort) that the data are already sorted from backend. So I guess to grouping work as expected, your backend should sort the data 1st by `group-by` column and then by any `sort-by` column...

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You are absolutely correct.